# How to migrate e-mail addresses from an old to a new domain, but allow to still send to the old e-mail addresses?

Tags: web-hosting, email, mail

Our company currently has a domain `old.example`.

Going forward, they want to use a new domain `new.example` as primary domain.

1. This means that we will host the new website on `new.example` and next, set a redirect from old.com to `new.example`. No problem here.
2. Going forward, we will make new e-mail addresses like `mail@new.example`.
3. My question is about dealing with the e-mails accounts already linked to old.com. 
   We would like to make the old e-mail addressess available via `mail@new.example`. 
   However, when somebody still mails to `mail@old.example`, the mail should still be received on `mail@new.example`.

Mailboxes will be hosted on Office 365. I will add both the old and new domain to Office 365.

How can we achieve this? Should we re-create all e-mail addresses with the domain `new.example` & then create a forward rule from `mail@old.example` to `mail@new.example`. There has to be a smarter way to do this? Some kind of alias method which can be used?

Comment: You're asking a question that is largely a matter for the mail server application to resolve, but you're talking like you expect some lower level entity like DNS to solve?

Comment: Does the process at https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/add-or-remove-a-user-s-email-alias-cb86b53b-bebf-4e0a-b781-c49270d85ea3 work for you? Everyone has a "real" mailbox of the new domain, and an alias attached to it of the old domain (o365 knows of both domains). Mails will deliver to the new boxes and replies and new mails will go out with the new domain on so gradually the world will (should) convert to using the new domain. I put as a comment because I cannot verify (not having o365) that it will be acceptable, but let me know if it works out and I'll post as answer

Comment: @CaiusJard I will try it. Waiting to receive the admin credentials now. The dropdown part for the domain is interesting for me as then I will probably need to create an alias with the same local part before the @, e.g. ‘info’ & then pick the new domain from the dropdown. Don’t know if it will be possible to pick the same local part twice for an alias however...

Comment: Should be a fairly common use case; everywhere I've worked has had several domains (to prevent fake mimic site scams) and I've had caius.jard@(all domains) as aliases of the main mailbox to catch any mistyped emails

Comment: OK, great. I appreciate your help. I’ll let you know when I’ve implemented this at the customer!

Comment: @CaiusJard This solution did work for me, so thank you for that. If you like, put it in an answer and I’ll mark it as correct and give you some credit. Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the process at https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/add-or-remove-a-user-s-email-alias-cb86b53b-bebf-4e0a-b781-c49270d85ea3 can be used, with the old address as the alias and the new address as the primary. a précis of the process is replicated below to ward against link rot:

### Add email aliases to a user

You must have admin permissions in Microsoft 365 to do this.

- Sign in with your Microsoft 365 admin account on the Microsoft 365 admin center.
- Select Users.
- On the Active users page, choose the user.
- Next to User name / Email, choose Edit.. Note: new users can take 30 minutes to fully provision
- On the Edit email addresses page, in the text box under Alias, type the first part of the new email alias and picks domain,  then choose Add.
- choose Save.

Wait 24 hours for the new aliases to populate throughout Microsoft 365.

The user now has a primary address and an alias. All mail sent to either address goes to their inbox. The primary address will be the From address when sending new mail

Everyone has a "real" mailbox of the new domain, and an alias attached to it of the old domain (o365 knows of both domains). Mails will deliver to the new boxes and replies and new mails will go out with the new domain on so gradually the world will (should) convert to using the new domain.